# Add secondary x-axis to ggplot line graph, purely for information

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have a graph that shows plant development over time. As time, I use growing degree days (its basically a combined measure of time and temperature). Now I would like to add a second x-axis at the top that shows the 'real' time, ie weeks from the start of the experiment, so that the viewer can have a clearer idea of what happened when. Because of the nature of growing degree days, they can't be converted to weeks in any mathematical way. So I would have to individually add the information, eg 1 week is at 500 gdd, 2 weeks at 800 gdd, 3 weeks at 1400 gdd. This information wouldn't in any way correspond with the content of the graph itself.

Here is my simple code for a graph with growing degree days.

```
my.df<-data.frame(ccc=seq(0,15,1),gdd=seq(0,1500,100))
ggplot(data=my.df, aes(x=gdd, y=ccc))+
  geom_line()
```

Now all I would need are axis ticks at the top at 500, 800 and 1400 gdd that say 1, 2 and 3 and an axis label that says "weeks".
Is there a way of doing that? My only idea so far is to add it in photoshop, but thats cheating :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sec_axis()` for this. Since you basically just want to label a few positions manually you don't have to worry about a complicated transformation.

```
ggplot(data=my.df, aes(x=gdd, y=ccc))+
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(
        trans = ~ .,
        name = "Weeks",
        breaks = c(500, 800, 1400), 
        labels = c(1, 2, 3)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have an added question. What if instead of adding weeks, I want to add calendar months? The axis ticks would work the same way, but the axis tick labels would have to be positioned between 2 ticks, eg if jan had lasted from 0 to 500 gdd, feb from 500 to 800, and march from 800 to 1400. Would that be possible as well?

Comment: Having tick labels appear between ticks can be tricky in `ggplot`, especially since it seems like `sec_axis()` doesn't support having `minor_breaks`. Sometimes it's better to use `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` for that kind of thing.

Comment: Actually, I just found a way to do the month thing (if somewhat inelegantly) by removing the labels from your suggestion, and adding a text annotation instead, with the clipping in `coord_cartesian()` turned off. Just adding it here for the record.